# Run button not working when emulator is running (it doesn't rerun)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am used to compile the application on the emulator and when making any changes, I play the run button, the application gets closed on the emulator and replaced with the new version.

But recently this stopped working, the first time I open the emulator works fine, but if I press the Run button again I get:

> Error while waiting for device: AVD Pixel_4_API_30 is already running.
> If that is not the case, delete the files at
> C:\Users\MyUser.android\avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/*.lock
> and try again.

The thing is, yes, it is already running, and that's expected. I don't know why it does complain about it.

For now, I'm using the workaround of stopping the emulator every time I want to press the Run button so it gets started again.

Plus the restart button shows this message, which contradicts the run error message:

Apply Changes and Restart Activity (disabled: device not connected)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded the Android Studio version and now it detects my physical device and allows to rerun the app on the emulator.

It seems to be a bug on the latest version.